# disabling an onload javascript popup function

Tags: jquery, event-handling, onload-event

I have a dynamic onload popup that I need to disable if the request is loaded into an iframe. I assume using an eventlistener may be the best approach, but I am unfamiliar with this object.

What would be the best usage in this case.

Thanks

Comment: Is your onload attached to the window?

Comment: yes it is. The onload event is coded into the body.